# Java8 Stream API: map, groupingBy to different objects

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I'm fairly new to Java8. I have a requirement to convert List of plain objects to group by a certain criteria and show it on UI.

- The key to the map should be combination of "fromDate-todate" and the
  list of students should be associated to this combination.
- Also, the 'ClassOfMsSwan' object needs to be converted to 'Student' object and saved into the list.
- Code for Java1.7 has been written and needs to
  be converted to Java1.8.

Kindly help me out.

```
public class ClassOfMsSwan {

private String fromDate;
private String toDate;
private String studentName;
private String subject;
private String marks;

public ClassOfMsSwan(String fromDate, String toDate, String studentName, String subject, String marks) {
    super();
    this.fromDate = fromDate;
    this.toDate = toDate;
    this.studentName = studentName;
    this.subject = subject;
    this.marks = marks;
}
// setters and getters


public class Student {

private String name;
private String subject;
private String marks;
public Student(String name, String subject, String marks) {
    this.marks = marks;
    this.subject = subject;
    this.name = name;
}   
// setters and getters




List<ClassOfMsSwan> classes = new ArrayList<>();

    ClassOfMsSwan classOfMsSwan1 = new ClassOfMsSwan("06/01/2016", "05/31/2017", "David", "Physics", "98");
    ClassOfMsSwan classOfMsSwan2 = new ClassOfMsSwan("06/01/2016", "05/31/2017", "Jane", "Botany", "85");
    ClassOfMsSwan classOfMsSwan3 = new ClassOfMsSwan("06/01/2016", "05/31/2017", "Mathew", "Algebra", "76");

    ClassOfMsSwan classOfMsSwan4 = new ClassOfMsSwan("06/01/2017", "05/31/2018", "David", "Geometry", "94");
    ClassOfMsSwan classOfMsSwan5 = new ClassOfMsSwan("06/01/2017", "05/31/2018", "Jane", "Organic Chemistry", "92");
    ClassOfMsSwan classOfMsSwan6 = new ClassOfMsSwan("06/01/2017", "05/31/2018", "Mathew", "Botany", "100");

    ClassOfMsSwan classOfMsSwan7 = new ClassOfMsSwan("06/01/2018", "05/31/2019", "Mathew", "Geometry", "86");
    ClassOfMsSwan classOfMsSwan8 = new ClassOfMsSwan("06/01/2018", "05/31/2019", "Jane", "Algebra", "84");

    classes.add(classOfMsSwan1);
    classes.add(classOfMsSwan2);
    classes.add(classOfMsSwan3);
    classes.add(classOfMsSwan4);
    classes.add(classOfMsSwan5);
    classes.add(classOfMsSwan6);
    classes.add(classOfMsSwan7);
    classes.add(classOfMsSwan8);

    // JDK1.7
    Map<String, List<Student>> dateStudentMap = new HashMap<>();
    for(ClassOfMsSwan classOfMsSwan : classes) {
        List<Student> students = dateStudentMap.get(classOfMsSwan.getFromDate() + "-" + classOfMsSwan.getToDate());
        if(CollectionUtils.isEmpty(students)) {
            students = new ArrayList<>();
            dateStudentMap.put(classOfMsSwan.getFromDate() + "-" + classOfMsSwan.getToDate(), students);
        }
        students.add(new Student(classOfMsSwan.getStudentName(), classOfMsSwan.getSubject(), classOfMsSwan.getMarks()));
    }


Desired output
   {06/01/2016-05/31/2017=[Student [name=David, subject=Physics, marks=98], Student [name=Jane, subject=Botany, marks=85], Student [name=Mathew, subject=Algebra, marks=76]], 06/01/2017-05/31/2018=[Student [name=David, subject=Geometry, marks=94], Student [name=Jane, subject=Organic Chemistry, marks=92], Student [name=Mathew, subject=Botany, marks=100]], 06/01/2018-05/31/2019=[Student [name=Mathew, subject=Geometry, marks=86], Student [name=Jane, subject=Algebra, marks=84]]}
```

Comment: Have a look at [Collectors Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html). It also contains examples and convenience methods to get you started.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this use Java 8 API like this:

```
Map<String, Set<Student>> dateStudentMap = classes.stream().map(e ->  
                new Entry(e.getFromDate() + "-" + e.getToDate(),
                        new Student(e.getStudentName(), e.getSubject(), e.getMarks())
            ))
    .collect(groupingBy(Entry::getKey, TreeMap::new,
            mapping(Entry::getValue, toSet())));
```

where I use a primitive helper class `Entry` defined like below:

```
class Entry{
    public Entry(String key, Student value){
        this.setKey(key);
        this.setValue(value);
    }
    //getters and setters

    private String key;
    private Student value;
}
```

Hope that helps.

**EDIT:**

Acorrding to Holger's comment (it is much better):

```
    Map<String, Set<Student>> dateStudentMap8 = classes.stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(e -> 
                        e.getFromDate() + "-" + e.getToDate(),
                        mapping(e -> 
                            new Student(e.getStudentName(), 
                                        e.getSubject(), 
                                        e.getMarks()), 
                            toSet())));
```

Comment: There is no need for this `Entry` helper class. Just use `classes.stream() .collect(groupingBy(e -> e.getFromDate() + "-" + e.getToDate(), mapping(e -> new Student(e.getStudentName(), e.getSubject(), e.getMarks()), toSet())));` It’s also unclear why you enforce the use of a `TreeMap` when the OP clearly used a `HashMap`…

Comment: Your comment is a much better answer, I edited mine according to it, thanks!

Comment: Thank you ! This is what exactly what I wanted !